# Using the UNIQUE() function in a dynamic dropdown list with Excel

Tags: excel, unique, dynamic-list

I am trying to make a dynamic dependent drop-down list without taking into consideration zeros or empty cells with the UNIQUE() function in Excel. However, whenever i write the UNIQUE() command in the data validation tab, Excel always returns:

"The Source currently evaluates to an error. Do you want to continue?"

Here is what i'm trying to do:
[Explanation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UREGf.png)

In cell C4, i chose my category (so gaming, productivity, school, etc.). Columns I and J are here in case in the future, I want to add more categories. Then, in cell D4, depending on the category selected on cell C4, it will return the products of that category. However, forget about cell D4 for this question, once I figure out the category problem, I think I can find a solution by myself!

I first wrote: =UNIQUE(F1:J1;TRUE;TRUE) in an empty cell to verify if the function works and it does. The cells I1 and J1 don't appear, exactly how i want it to be. Now I need that in a dropdown list and so this is what I did:
[List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kc6kI.png)

However, like I said earlier, Excel returns an error... Does someone know why? I even tried naming the range F1 to J1 as "Category" and wrote =UNIQUE(Category;TRUE;TRUE) but it still comes up with an error...

Comment: Put the function in a hidden sheet.  Then refer to that range using the `#` notation, ie: `=Sheet2!A1#` DataValidation does not accept dynamic arrays.

Comment: Wow, it's funny how it was THAT simple, thank you so much!!

Comment: So I have another problem... I did a depend list for the products column (column D) but this works ONLY IF the list is in one row and one cell only. What if I wanted to have multiple rows of choices? In other words, instead of having a list in cell C4, I'd have a list in cells C4, C5, C6, C7 (until C14 for example) and i'd get the corresponding products. I tried the "drag and drop" with the corner of the cell D4 (where the data validation is) but when i check the source, the reference cell is always C4 even though I need it to be C5, C6, C7, etc.

Comment: Sorry clarification: "instead of havin a list in ***cells C4 AND D4***, i wanted to have lists in cells C4-D4, C5-D5, C6-D6 (since the column D is dependent of column C)!

Comment: That is a new question, New Questions get New Posts with their own clarifications

Comment: Sorry, I made a new post. I don't use stackoverflow very often. Thank you!